# Viruses affecting transmission capability of mosquitoes

Tags: microbiology, entomology, virus, virology

I've read about bacteria affecting the transmission capability of mosquitoes. For example:

- *Wolbachia* [suppresses dengue transmission](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v476/n7361/full/nature10356.html)
- When mosquitoes were given antibiotics that decreased their gut microbiota diversity, [they became more susceptible to malaria infection](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2015/150106/ncomms6921/full/ncomms6921.html)

Have there been any studies to show that the presence of certain viruses/viral diversity (rather than bacteria) has an effect on the tranmission of other viruses/pathogens?

Answer (score 1):

There have been some studies looking at this, but not many. One is [this study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17172379) which reported an interaction between *Aedes* densovirus (AeDNV) and dengue virus (DENV) in *Aedes albopictus*: mosquitoes already infected with AeDNV were more resistant to infection with DENV, although DENV infection appeared to accelerate the replication of the existing AeDNV infection. A similar interaction [was not seen](https://parasitesandvectors.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1756-3305-3-95) with chikungunya virus (CHIKV).

In addition there are indirect interactions between pathogens of all kinds - viruses such as AeDNV which kill a high proportion of the mosquitoes they infect reduce the average survival and population density of the vector and therefore the ability of the local population to transmit disease ([ref](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S104996440600123X)).